# Win7 Powershell 4 sls pattern to match lines without string A but with string B

Tags: regex, powershell

With Win 7 and Powershell 4, I need to list all files in a directory that have a line that does not contain "`CIC`" but does contain ",`IA`,".  I am able to find files with lines containing ",`IA`," by using

```
"dir -recurse *.* | sls -pattern ",IA," | select -unique filename"
```

but can't figure out how to modify this to exclude lines that also contain "`CIC`"

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude them with look-arounds:

```powershell
dir -recurse . | sls -pattern "(?<!CIC),IA,(?!=CIC)" | select -unique filename
```

This says "find `,IA,` if not pre-ceded or followed by `CIC`".

You might consider doing this without `Select-String` (`sls`):

```
dir -recurse . | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*,IA,*" -and $_.Name -notlike "*CIC*" } | select -unique filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be easily solved with `switch` statement. Also, I consider your strings are **case sensitive**.

```
#requires -v 3
dir c:\...\?.txt | %{
        $hasIAwithCommasCaseSensitive,$hasCICcaseSensitive=$false,$false
        switch -w -c -f $_{
            '*,IA,*' {$hasIAwithCommasCaseSensitive=$true}
            '*CIC*' {$hasCICcaseSensitive=$true;break}
        }
        if($hasIAwithCommasCaseSensitive -and -not $hasCICcaseSensitive){$_}
    }
```

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'll stick with your `Select-String` method, but I'll have it search for both terms, and return all matches. Then group the results by file (I'll use the `Path` property in case you wanted to do it recursively and had identically named files). Then pass the results through a `Where` statement that will drill down into each file's result group to the matches from `Select-String` that were returned, and make sure that 'CIC' is not included.

```psh
Get-ChildItem .\* -file | Select-String -Pattern "CIC|,AI," -AllMatches | Group Path | Where{$_.group.matches.value -notcontains "CIC"} | Select -expand Name
```

Plus since we already grouped them we only have unique paths. If you want unique files (such as having Contacts.txt in two locations, but only returning one value) you would have to do a little extra processing, like piping them all to `Split-Path -leaf` and then selecting unique values.